# Handling data flow in iOS 17 and using observed variables inside a TextField

Tags: swiftui, observable, textfield, bindable, ios17

I'm trying to migrate to iOS 17 using `@Observable`.

I have a global view model of the app where I call an Exam model with all the values ​​I need inside.

According to [Apple guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro) I'm using my view model like this

```
import Foundation
import Observation

struct Exam: {
    var title: String = ""
}


@Observable
final class Global {
    var exam = Exam()
}
```

---

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @State private var model = Global()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            InfoView()
                .environment(model)
                
        }
    }
}
```

Next I use my model within the InfoView like this

```
struct InfoView: View {
   // @Bindable private var model = Global()
    @Environment(Global.self) private var model

    var body: some View {
         VStack {
             TitledField(text: $model.exam.title, isMandatory: true, descriptionLabel: "", placeholder: "")
             .submitLabel(.continue)

          }
     }
}
```

As you can see in the first custom textField I use `$model.exam.title` but it doesn't seem to work because it gives me this error

> Cannot find '$model' in scope

So I tried with `@Bindable` but the value that the user inserts in the textField is not read and always returns an empty string where am I going wrong? Has anyone started working on iOS 17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example code with `@Bindable` works for me on iOS17.
When the `$model.exam.title` is changed in the `TextField`,
the UI is refreshed and displays the changed value.

```
import SwiftUI
import Observation

 @main
 struct TestApp: App {
     @State private var model = Global()
      var body: some Scene {
          WindowGroup {
              InfoView(model: model) // <-- here
          }
      }
 }
 
 struct InfoView: View {
     @Bindable var model: Global // <-- here
     var body: some View {
          VStack {
              TextField("", text: $model.exam.title).border(.red)
                  .submitLabel(.continue)
              
              Text(model.exam.title) // <-- for testing
           }
      }
 }

struct Exam {
    var title: String = "exam-title"
}

@Observable
final class Global {
    var exam = Exam()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `@Environment` you need to convert to `@Bindable`, e.g.

```
@Bindable var exam = model.exam
TitledField(text: $exam.title, isMandatory: true, descriptionLabel: "", placeholder: "")
```

`@Bindable` isn't a `DynamicProperty` so it can be used inside `body` like any other struct.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

I added a sample project with "add" too:

https://github.com/ingconti/iOS17_ObservableLibraryView